# Play SWF Files on Android Device Without Flash Player Plugin and without webview

Tags: android, flash

I have few SWF Files which I want to run view on my Android Device.
Earlier I was viewing those files in webview using flash player but now as flash player plugin is no more available on play store so the person who has not flash player plugin already can not view those files.

How can I show my SWF files without using Flash Player Plugin ?

Comment: you can't play swf file without any plugin

Comment: Then which plugin should i use? i have already tried all these flash players.. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=swf+player..  Is there not any alternate solution?

Comment: no alternative solution just think your pc also not play swf file with out plugins!

Comment: because,flash is adobe products is need for flashplayer plugin it's only can view,play and execute flash scripts

Comment: i know but as u can also check that adobe flash player is no more available on play store then what shoud i do next?

Comment: adobe flash plugin removed on playstore by adobe after android ics released because, many bugs occurs to ics and higher version!

Comment: @VaishaliSharma Did you find any solution?! Same problem here

Comment: @Dr.jacky     Did you find any solution?! Same problem here

Comment: @Sudhirsingh It was for three years ago and I can not remember correctly, but I think the answer is no; sorry.

Comment: hi  @VaishaliSharma   Did you find any solution?! Same problem here

Answer (score 4):

You can use opensource code like [SWFDec](http://swfdec.freedesktop.org/wiki/), but you have to porting it on android by yourself.

How to porting:
  1. download swfdec source code from http://swfdec.freedesktop.org
  2. cross-compile swfdec source code for android platform
  3. read swfdec source code to find how to blit swfdec surface to android view

Comment: @VaishaliSharma How did you solve this issue ? Did you actually port swfdec on andorid ?

Comment: No, actually i used Adobe Flash Player to run SWF Files.

Answer (score 4):

Google's Swiffy makes Flash files HTML5 friendly.

Google's cooked up a new tool in its labs that converts SWF files into HTML5 for use on devices that can't run Flash, including those made by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I use Adobe AIR for swf files to play b'cause its still free, **but it does require you to sign up**.. Here is setup require to getting started with [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/inspire-archive/august2010/articles/article1/index.html?trackingid=HRTDI).. There is lot of stuff in that link well, you require only app, for viewing .swf file...

Comment: well, as i said its available free, its just what I used for time being just to save me from client pressure.. and yes, even i did had some issues while playing some .swf files, but for most it worked fine. for those I couldn't play I converted to .mp4 or any other Android compatible format using any available convertors. I know this is not a rigid answer, but hey free app, client happy for now, wait till something interesting comes up which is free  obcourse..

Comment: @CRUSADER did you open Adobe Air from your developed Android application pragmatically? I mean for playing video it will go to Adobe Air? Which converter you used to convert SWF to MP4? I tried many but none of them works well..

Answer (score 0):

Firefox comes with SWF support. I had to play a SWF file in Android. Here's how I did it.

1. Download the SWF file to store locally in your device. Most likely by default it will be in the root/sdcard/download folder.
2. Open Firefox browser. Type in the URL file://root/sdcard/download/myFlashFilename.swf

   It should show a "Tap to activate plugin" or similar message. Tap it and it should work.
3. Add this to Bookmark and Add to Home Screen for easy access.