# Loading SWF file in android

Tags: android, flash

I need to play swf file in my application, I searched google lot and finally come with following code, But my `webview` still blank,

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            String html = "<object width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_asset/newlifeacu.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///android_asset/newlifeacu.swf\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> </embed> </object>";
String mimeType = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
mWebView.loadData(html, mimeType, encoding);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Note: I want to play 4.1 or higher.

Any help will be highly appreciable, Please help  friends.
Thanks & Regards,
Guna

Comment: Did you see this - http://swfdec.freedesktop.org/wiki/ ?

Comment: Also - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874647/2956344