# Is there any way to load swf file into andoird

Tags: android, flash, android-webview

I am loading SWF file into Andriod.

I am trying with webview, but there is an error couldn't load plug-in

```
String text="<html>\n" +
        "  <head>\n" +
        "    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html\" charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n" +
        "  </head>\n" +
        "  <body>\n" +
        "<h1>jvjhvjhv</h1>\n"+
        "    <object width=\"215\" height=\"140\">\n" +
        "      <param name=\"movie\" value=\"airplane.swf\">\n" +
        "        <embed src=\"file:///android_asset/airplane.swf\"\n" +
        "               width=\"215\" height=\"140\">\n" +
        "        </embed>\n" +
        "    </object>\n" +
        "  </body>\n" +
        "</html>";
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Android; rv:48.0) Gecko/48.0 Firefox/48.0 KAIOS/2.0");

    mWebView.loadData(text,"text/html","utf-8");
}
```

Can anyone give me an answer to load SWF file in android?

Thank you

Comment: Have u checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874647/7666442

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962816/open-swf-file-in-android-5-workarounds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play SWF Files on Android Device Without Flash Player Plugin and without webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247487/play-swf-files-on-android-device-without-flash-player-plugin-and-without-webview)

Answer (score 1):

> *"I am loading SWF file into Android.
>
>   I am trying with WebView, but there is an error saying `"Could not load plug-in"`.
>
>   Can anyone give me an answer to load SWF file in Android?"*

You could try: [**SWF 2 JS**](https://github.com/swf2js/swf2js). You want to save this file [**swf2js.js**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swf2js/swf2js/master/swf2js.js) and use in your own HTML code.

Success will depend on your SWF file content. `SWF2JS` supports Flash animations and AS2 code.

- I've not tested this in an Android WebView (with dynamic HTML string) but on PC it expects files to be accessed from either online or else via device's localhost server.
- If any problems loading an animation. Try using files from location: `https://` not `file:///`.

**Demos** (test if these can display on your Android device) :

1) Flash graphics: https://vcone.github.io/public/flash/demo1.html

2) Game with code: https://vcone.github.io/public/flash/demo2.html

If the above SWF files work on Android, then you can try some embed code like below:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/swf2js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

ADROID TEST: Displaying SWF with JavaScript and HTML5 Canvas... <br><br>

<div id="myFlashDiv" style="width:800px; height:800px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var mySWF = swf2js;
mySWF.load('file:///android_asset/airplane.swf', {"tagId": "myFlashDiv"});

</script>

</body>
```