# How to display Flash File (swf) with Python

Tags: python-3.x, flash

I need to find a way to display some swf file with Python 3. I know flash is dead in 2019, but I need to do it for a mini app. All my research led me around PySwf, but impossible to run. Some of modules missing, in particular tag module. 
Another way exist to display swf file with Python ?

Answer (score 0):

I think PySWF can only just process the SWF bytes (extract or add data). It does not display.

**(1)** You could try using some Python web browser module to check if your file will work. Also see if embedding the SWF in HTML page via [SWF2JS](https://github.com/swf2js/swf2js) works with your file. Basic test [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57015598/2057709) of usage.

**(2)** Find the correct `Download the Flash Player projector` for your OS from [Flash Player downloads](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html) and run it (as external app) from Python. Test in terminal (or command-line) via:

```
path-to-your-FlashPlayer yourFlash.swf
```

Comment: In fact, I need to do a diaporama with some files extension like png/jpg/swf/html etc..So it needed to display the SWF file in Full Screen. I have done the program for display the rest of extension but can't find a solution for this flash files. So, I don't know if your first solution is good for my situation.
I search one solution to display this extension look like Pygame for the global picture for example.