# Flash script not working in html on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, flash

I have flash video in html code and it works IE and Firefox but not show in chrome. I also try another solution that i search found but it's still not working. I want to show on my website.

Here is my embed with script call

```
<script type="text/javascript">AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0','width','1000','height','485','src','flash/flash','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','movie','flash/flash' );</script>


<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="1000" height="485">
        <param name="movie" value="flash/flash.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600px" height="1300px" src="flash.swf" wmode="transparent"></embed>
    </object>
```

How can i fix it? Thank you for any answer help me.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend using flash. This is because Flash will no longer be supported by Adobe, and most browsers will retire the Flash function at the end of 2020.

Comment: Hi, it's necessary to use this before to change the new website i have to show this while waiting new website finish.

Comment: Have you checked if you allowed flash to be used in Chrome? Flash is blocked by default.

Comment: Maybe this can help you:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: from my site it's allowed but for user who go to site they still see require for flash and if i open in mobile it's not show anything.

Comment: That's correct, because by default Chrome disables Flash. This is not something you can enable from your website, because it is client side. You can fix this by adding a popup that tells the user to enable Flash. For mobile Chrome there is no support for Flash at all, so it wouldn't work for mobile devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the code for now and will wait for new site.

Answer (score 1):

**(1) To display in Chrome**

Use `embed` tag not `object` tag. Those six lines of code you show can be replaced by just this one line...

```
<embed src="flash/flash.swf" wmode="transparent" width="600" height="1300">
```

Try this code below with your link (in a new page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed src="flash/flash.swf" wmode="transparent" width="600" height="1300">

</body>
</html>
```

**(2) To display in mobile browsers**

Option 1: 
Use a browser that supports Flash content like Dolphin or Penguin etc.

Option 2: 
 
Try to find some JavaScript library that displays SWF in some HTML5 element (or maybe even converts the content into HTML5 code).

One such library is [**SWF 2 JS**](https://github.com/swf2js/swf2js). See if my other answer about that is helpful to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57015598/2057709.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Flash only works in the browser where the flash plugin is installed.

For example, I have the default browser setting disabled for flash. It is better to rewrite or convert flash to html video if possible. There are also online convertor.

Do you have any information in the console?

Comment: Yes, I know it's already too old. I have to use flash while new website is finish.
Nothing show in the console.

Comment: And did you try just convert into html video ? I did in my project and works fine. Just try same online convertor. It will be better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It's look like image sliding using flash but now i changed the code to normal sliding https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp