# Moving from Flex - mxml (action scripts) to another technology

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5, mxml

Adobe's Flash has reached the end of the road so all applications has to be rewritten in different tech stack. we have big application written using flex. we have around 400 mxml (+action script) files and it uses java as backend technology. 
so have couple of questions here -

1. Is there any converter tool that understands mxml file and can give html5 or javascript components as output?
2. if there is no tool available, what is the closest technology we should use? I tried with React for UI and in java backend, converted flex method to REST API. This exercise is time consuming and need complete rewrite of both UI and backend.
3. Is there any other browser plugin that can understand compiled mxml or action scripts (after compilation - .swf file)?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: See if **SWF2JS** will run your app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57015598/2057709. Otherwise provide more info about your app and the `.AS` Classes it uses. A temporary preview (online demo page) of your SWF would **help us to see how to help you**. To answer your questions: **(1)** Nope. This is why some 2 years ago, a notice to begin _"time consuming task"_ of code converting was given by Adobe to everyone. **(2)** Try **SWF2JS** to decode & display SWF via JS code. **(3)** Flash is ending because **all major browsers** are ending plugins. From 2020 onwards we'll have a no-plugin internet.

Comment: Try by all means to provide the app through Adobe AIR (i.e. as a desktop application). Of course it may be difficult to convince your management or your users, but any other option is a mountain of work. Automatic translators won't give you working and readable code, and rewriting in Angular or React or Vue (popular choices for conversion from Flex) takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The "easiest" way would be using the next version of Flex, [Apache Royale](https://royale.apache.org/).

This will allow you to keep all your actionscript parts of the code and rewrite only the UI part with the new MXML components. It has a bit of a learning curve as many things are done a bit differently, but you don't have to change your AS3 code.